# Icon in shared action with sub action does not appear

Tags: icons, action, lotus-notes, shared, lotus-domino

When you add a shared action to a sub action the icon used in the top level menu disappears. In past I solved the problem by re-selecting the icon and saving, but now this is not working anymore. I am using Lotus Notes 8.5.2. Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things that work for me:

- re-arrange your sub-actions so that the top action is not a shared action
- add a menu separator above the shared action.  The separator does not show but seems to force the action button to use the correct icon.

Comment: First statement is true. I have only one sub-action, so I can't use the first option. How can I make the second option work?

Comment: Create a standard (non-shared) sub-action above your shared sub-action.  Open the Action Properties.  Change Type from Button to Menu Separator.

Comment: Just curious - why do you need a sub-action if there is only one? Why not just add your shared action at the top level?

Comment: For the moment there is only sub-action. In the future is possible to have multiple shared sub-actions. Then it will be a happy situation if I have a first non shared action.

Comment: I've tried to add a standard sub-action with the menu separator type, but with no success.

Comment: Not quite sure why it doesn't work for you - works fine for me.  Do you have an icon assigned to the shared action?  Does it show that icon or nothing?  I tested using 8.5.2 and having first sub-action as a menu separator then the shared action forced the main action button to use its assigned icon.  I was using a standard Notes icon, not a custom icon - don't know if that makes a difference

Comment: I've followed your advice. I've creaded a new shared action with sub-action, emptied the name of the default sub-action and changed the type to menu separator. Then I've added a shared action after the menu separator type action. Set the icon as Lotus Notes and choosed "Only show icon in Action bar", saved, changed with a custom image and then saved again. It works. Thank you.